# Only show alert once per element on DOMNodeInserted

Tags: jquery

I have a button that creates a div with the class "mynewdiv".  This div can be destroyed and recreated as many times as the user likes.

I want to add an event listener for when the div is inserted like so:

```
$('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', 'div.mynewdiv', function () {
    alert('hi');
});
```

However the alert box fires multiple times each time the div is inserted.

I'm using a 3rd party plugin which I cannot change - hence using the event listener.  Is there a way in jQuery to fire the alert only once?

I've tried using `.one` on the event listener, but that makes it fire literally once, rather than once per insert.

I could create a counter, but I was hoping there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: What exactly is the behaviour you're trying to create? The `DOMNodeInserted` will only fire once per element anyway, so the issue you have is not clear.

Comment: @Lee please clarify. Rory and my answer are relevant depending on what exactly you need.

Comment: I thought DOMNodeInserted would only fire once per element too.  Maybe it's because the div being inserted contains many other elements? I can't see how the plugin works so can only guess based off the results I see.  There is only 1 div with that class, however that div contains multiple elements so is it possible that is the cause?

Comment: `Maybe it's because the div being inserted contains many other elements?` Yes, that would cause the behaviour as the event will bubble up the DOM. If you're adding child elements within `mynewdiv` you'll need to call `stopPropagation` on their event

Comment: @lee still not 100% sure of what you need; but you can also check out https://github.com/pie6k/jquery.initialize

Answer (score 1):

A rudimentary fix:

```
var firedOnce = false;
$('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', 'div.mynewdiv', function () {
  if (firedOnce == false) {
    alert('hi');
    firedOnce = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: U can use $('body').find('div.mynewdiv')

Comment: @YannickIngenierie that doesn't seem relevant to this answer at all.

Comment: This is logically the same as using `one()` which the OP states doesn't work. Exactly what they're trying to do really isn't clear, though.

Comment: I complete :  'if (!$('body').find('div.mynewdiv')){alert('hi');}'

Comment: That's still not relevant, and actually breaks the logic.